# checking if malloc'ed pointer is NULL

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following code (simplified for here).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct inner {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct outer {
    struct inner *next;
    struct inner *prev;

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct outer *c = malloc(sizeof(struct outer));

    if (c->next) {
        printf("here\n");
    }

    if (c->next != NULL) {
        printf("here too");
    }
}
```

As you can see above, `c` only has memory allocated, so `c->next` and `c->prev` are NULL addresses. But both print statements still run. How do I get the `if` statement to work only if `c->next` is not a null pointer?

Comment: Before you check any members in your allocated memory, you should check if malloc'ed pointer is `NULL`. This means you must check `c` against `NULL` before you touch any member. Which are not set to `NULL` as already explained in the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A.  `malloc()` does not initialize memory to zero, so your pointers are not necessarily `NULL`

B.  accessing an uninitialized pointer results in undefined behavior

C. `c->next` and `c->next != NULL` are basically the same condition check

Answer (score 5):

You have allocated memory using `malloc()` that does not guarantee that memory is set to zeros
If you had used `calloc()`, all the memory would have been set to zero and you would have found `c->next` and `c->prev` to `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption

> As you can see above, c only has memory allocated, so c->next and c->prev are NULL addresses

is the issue. Although you did allocate memory for the outer struct, there is no guarantees that it has been 0 initialized. The pointers presumably point to garbage addresses.

If you wanted to have them be `NULL`, you could:

```
struct outer *c = malloc(sizeof(struct outer));
memset(c, 0, sizeof(struct outer));
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the pointer to anything yet. You only allocated space for it, but you **did not initialize it**.

Allocating space does not automatically initialize anything.